# Git inside of Sublimetext

Tags: git

I get the following error:

```
    You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
Please, commit your changes before you can merge.
```

I would like to merge the changes, but I cannot find any <<< in my code with Sublimetext, so I cannot see any git changes.

Can you tell me which editor I can use or how I can display the merge heads step by step?

I have already installed package control in git and tried to install a package to highlight git changes, but I use Mac and its not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The merge markers (`<<<` and `>>>`) are not what makes this fail. Once you fix the merge and remove the markers from the conflicting files, you need to *add* the merged file to the index and commit.

So you would want to do:

```
git add file-that-had-conflicts
git commit
```

If you commit from inside Sublime Text, then you still need to add the merged file first to the index.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot see the merge markers. Add I used git add . so I had already added all the files.

Comment: If you cannot see the merge markers, then there is no further conflict you need to resolve. Check `git status` to see what you still need to do before you can commit the merge.